# Can't grab information from POST form

Tags: python, django, post

I'm new to Django and web development in general. I am currently playing around with the forms, but I can't seem to get the POST form data.

models.py

```
class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    transmission = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    number_plate = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

views.py

```
def car_detail_view(request):
form = BookCar()
obj = Car.objects.get(number_plate="1JZ3OG")
context = {
    'obj': obj,
    'form': form
}
return render(request, "car/car_detail.html", context)

def book_car(request):
    form = BuyCar(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = models.Car.objects.get(number_plate=request.POST.get('number_plate'))
        instance.available=False
        return redirect('../../')
```

forms.py

```
class BookCar(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Car
    fields = [
        'brand',
        'transmission',
        'number_plate',
        'price',
        'available'
    ]
```

car_detail.html

```
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ obj.brand }}</h1>
<p>{{ obj.number_plate }}</p>
<p>{{ obj.price }}</p>
<p>{{ obj.available }}</p>
<form class="form" action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" value="{{obj.number_plate}}">
  <input type="submit" value="Book">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Every time I clicked on the Book button in the form, the book_car isn't getting the POST from the form. I've checked tutorials but I can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your views try like this

```
def book_car(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    field = request.POST.get('your-field-name')
```

Also in your template you should to do like this:

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

More info: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/